# SharePoint Online: Is it possible to modify / customize the root sharepoint.aspx site?

Tags: sharepoint-online, team-sites, microsoft-teams

In our scenario we need an overview of all teamsites and ms teams, a user has access to. So we need a landing page for the user with a listing of all his sharepoint online workspaces. The page /_layouts/15/sharepoint.aspx?v=sites already fulfills most of our needs, but we still need to customize things, like the design, hiding links or, as a bonus, add additional information.

Is it possible to change the sharepoint.aspx site? What are the limitations?

Comment: Seems like a valid question to me, sorry it got shut down, @sp4ce. The answer to your question however is "no".

Comment: Thanks for the kind words and for your answer! Then we'll need to use it the way it is or we have to find another way to build sth. similar. Thanks again!